# gcc start address

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded, bootloader, cortex-m

I am currently trying to compile a mbed project offline using gcc-arm-embedded but I want to change the start address as this program is intended to be used with a bootloader so will eventually have to run from 0x10000. I have exported my project as a GCC-ARM-EMBEDDED and am able to build the project with gcc. However I have no idea how to specify the start adress to 0x10000. I have tried to change the LPC1768.ld script, changing the ORIGIN of the FLASH to 0x10000, but it seems that it is not doing anything.

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 0x70000
  RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x100000C8, LENGTH = 0x7F38

  USB_RAM(rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x2007C000, LENGTH = 16K
  ETH_RAM(rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20080000, LENGTH = 16K
}
```

Is there an option in the Makefile or somewhere else that will help changing the start address of the program, so it can run correctly when I jump from my bootloader to adress 0x10000 ?

**EDIT:**

I think I understand what I need to achieve thanks to the couple of responses but for some reasons I can't get it working. Mbed does not export the startup_LPC17xx.s file so I tried to use the one from CMSIS, but no luck with that. I am wondering if I actually need to change the startup code as the process is as follow:

- Bootloader runs at 0x0000
- Bootloader will do some checks and eventually will run the user-app
  sitting at 0x10000. The bootloader actually moves the vector table
  before jumping to 0x10000. This user-app is the one I am trying to
  build with gcc and will not be running at power-up, only be running
  after the bootloader has started itself. Not sure if that's clear but
  I would think that only changing the Linker script would work... but it isn't.

Details of the Linker script where I have changed this section address to 0x10000:

> SECTIONS {

```
.text : 
{
    *startup_LPC17xx.o 
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    *(.text*)

    KEEP(*(.init))
    KEEP(*(.fini))

    /* .ctors */
    *crtbegin.o(.ctors)
    *crtbegin?.o(.ctors)
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o) .ctors)
    *(SORT(.ctors.*))
    *(.ctors)

    /* .dtors */
    *crtbegin.o(.dtors)
    *crtbegin?.o(.dtors)
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o) .dtors)
    *(SORT(.dtors.*))
    *(.dtors)

    *(.rodata*)

    KEEP(*(.eh_frame*))
} > FLASH

.ARM.extab : etc..
```

**EDIT2:** I have added *startup_LPC17xx.o in my script, this seems to be working fine now :)

Comment: Searching for "arm bare metal" on a search engine. I've found this one for example http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/simplest-bare-metal-program-for-arm/

Comment: So when you debug with gcc it doesn't blow away your bootloader and it jumps to your main function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linker file, specify a section that starts at 0x10000.  Then in your crt0 or similar startup code, you need to define your reset entry handler as residing in this section so the linker will put it there.  This could be via a `.section` or `#pragma` or similar mechanism.  You can verify by looking at the linker's generated map file to see that it is placing your reset handler at 0x10000.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have added some details to my question as the bootloader part is quite important to the understanding of what I want to achieve.

Comment: That actually makes sense and is working like a charm :) Sorry for late response but we had trouble compiling with GCC, all good now ! For the record I have edited the linker script of my question with the one currently working.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to change the LPC1768.ld script, changing the ORIGIN of
>   the FLASH to 0x10000, but it seems that it is not doing anything.

Check your Linker settings, whether you use the correct linker script. Changing the ORIGIN and size *works* here (LPC1768 with arm-none-eabi-gcc). Note that the resulting program will *not* execute on bare metal anymore, as the vector table will be at the wrong position: Your bootloader must be in place to start it.

Note that your bootloader must not jump to `0x10000` but load the reset vector from the table from `0x10004` into the PC. Bonus points when you load the MSP (Main Stack Pointer)  from `0x10000` just before.

Comment: Thanks for the help TurboJ, I have changed the LPC1768.ld script in "HelloWorld\mbed\LPC1768\GCC_ARM\".My makefile specifies the linker script as: "LINKER_SCRIPT = ./mbed/LPC1768/GCC_ARM/LPC1768.ld" .Now, if I build with ORIGIN of the FLASH to 0x10000 or ORIGIN to 0x00000, I get the exact same file. If I get rid of the LPC1768.ld file, gcc would complain, so I guess it is really using it. I think I understand the vector part as I was able to compile some projects with Keil uVision (at address 0x10000), but we are not yet looking at buying uVision to get over size limit, that's why we use gcc.